# If a one person business is supposed to refer to their business as "we", then how do you do this:

Tags: grammar

I want to try and sell my writing on the Internet. I have a registered business but it is just me. If I use "we" instead of "I" when building my site, how do I fix the "about" page? Is it not supposed to be about me and how I started writing?  I am confused.

I do not want it to look like I am lying. It is just me and I do all my writing, but I am registered with the state, and I do pay franchise taxes every year. 
I need help with how to word my about page since I have decided to try to sell some of my work. The way I have it worded now is about how I started writing and it is all about me, not "we".

Everybody says you are supposed to refer to a business as "we" but "we" does not exist. It is just me.
My url is [customizedwallpoems.com](http://customizedwallpoems.com/) if anyone would like to give me advice about my about page. I am not done so the site is not complete, but the about page is up, and it sounds more like a personal page than explaining how a business originated.

Thanks,
Donna

Comment: My suggestions:  (1) whereever you have we, put I and for us put me.  (2) If the "About Us" page talks about someone other than you -- perhaps your mother or husband or SO handles all the office work and getting the supplies -- then you can make it clear that there is someone else involved and go back to we and us.  But if it is just you, and you do everything from writing the poems to taking out the trash, then why not I and me?

Comment: You don't believe in paragraphs, do you? Apart from that, @ab2 is right.

Comment: However, I see that @Yay believes in paragraphs. You should hire her (or him), you need a secretary anyway.

Comment: @Ricky Maybe Donna could help you with comma splices.

Comment: @deadrat: [didactically] Grammar is your friend, not a deity to be worshipped mindlessly, Your Grace.

Comment: @Ricky I have made no comment on your grammar.  Punctuation is both a matter of style and politeness to your reader.  The former is to be weighed judiciously; the latter, is to be revered.

Comment: @deadrat: I stand corrected: punctuation, of course. [frightened] Certainly, Your Grace. Mea culpa. I'm a pathetic wretch. A chance to redeem myself, I beg you!

Comment: @Ricky Really?  Again?  Very well.  Ego te absolvo.  Vade et amplius iam noli peccare.

Comment: @deadrat: Merci beaucoup, Votre Grâce. Much obliged.

Comment: @Donna They get like this.  Ignore them.

Comment: @ab2: Ignore them, eh? Should the voice of liberty be mute?

Comment: You should use 'we' when you're talking about the business, and 'I' when you're talking about yourself. For example you write the stuff but the business prints and sells it.

Answer (score 4):

You need to proofread your website, which is charming but contains spelling and other errors. I think your "About Us" section should be re-named "About Me" for starters. You should say something like, "I was creating poetry before I could read or write," rather than "I started writing before I could read or write."

Anyone who can make money selling poetry these days is truly amazing! Best of luck with your new online venture.

Comment: Agreed. An apt remark often [(mis?-)attributed](http://quoteinvestigator.com/2015/06/13/we/) to Mark Twain holds that "Only kings, presidents, editors, and people with tapeworms have the right to use the editorial ‘we’."

Comment: @Donna  I agree with Mark's proofreading comment.  Make sure that you don't have an extra zero in the amount of money you made in 2.5 weeks, 35 years ago.

Answer (score 2):

**About This Poet**

Do not use the royal we. It's much over-rated and does not apply to the fact it is really you writing the poems. When needed use I, otherwise make sentences without any pronouns. We is for companies making widgets (physical or virtual), not for a person who writes poems.

About This Poet

Bringing your loved ones closer to you. [tagline]

[Narrative: For x years, I have been etc.

Answer (score 1):

> If I use "we" instead of "I" when building my site, how do I fix the "about" page?

Consider the distinction between the business and its people.

The business as a corporate entity engages in contracts, pays taxes, etc. When writing on behalf of the business, it is appropriate to use the corporate *we*. If you are composing an "about" page that talks about the corporate entity, you can call it "About Us", "About the Business", or "About Customized Wall Poems" if you don't want to use the generic single-word heading "About".

The business has individuals as staff, owners, contractors, etc. When writing as an individual, use the natural *I*. One style from a web search (I have no affiliation with the linked artist) is to use [the artist's name](http://iammartingeorge.com/about/) in the profile title, e.g. "About Donna". Alternatively, just use the single-word title "About". The content of the page should be self-explanatory; if it isn't and you are concerned about it, add a paragraph to clarify things.